# Array returning NaN for String values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I am writing a program to make a deck of cards by using suits and card values. I am running a for loop of suits and another nested for loop for cards inside suits loop and trying to print all the combinations(52) inside an empty array called "deck". While trying to log the deck array after the values are added, I am getting "NaN" in the values where there are strings in the deck array.

I know NaN means 'not a number' and that is why I am getting this error for printing string values in the array.

How do I print the string values?

Code:

```js
let suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"];
let cards = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

let deck = [];

for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < cards.length; j++) {
    deck.push(+cards[j] + "of" + suits[i]);
  }
}
console.log(deck[1]);
for (let k = 0; k < deck.length; k++) {
  console.log(deck[k]);
}
```

Comment: If you know why you're getting `NaN`, then what is the question?

Comment: How do I print the string values?

Comment: The coercion is not possible on this `+"Ace"`

Comment: Stop coercing them to numbers with `+cards[j]`?

Comment: **Why not only:** `deck.push(cards[j] + "of" + suits[i]);` you don't need coercion.

Comment: Got it. What is the difference between (+cards[j] + "of") and (cards[j] + "of")

Comment: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=whats+coercion+whats+not+js+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBR711BR711&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL8b-KldPgAhVdEbkGHc5uB_UQrQIoBDAMegQICRAM&biw=1440&bih=766)

Answer (score 2):

```
deck.push(+cards[j] + "of" + suits[i]);
```

TO

```
deck.push(cards[j] + "of" + suits[i]);
```

This [unary operator](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce) `+variable` will try to cast the value to a number, similar to `parseInt()` or `Number()`. You can't cast the string `"Ace"` to a number so instead it returns `"NaN"` and concatenates that to the beginning of your string.

You actually don't need this unary operator because by concatenating a number with a String (`+ "of" +`) you will already be coercing your integers to Strings, which is the data type you're trying to achieve in this scenario.

*Coercion in JS:* [JavaScript type coercion explained](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839)

And to write more concisely with **ES6**..

```
var deck = [].concat(
    ...suits.map(suit =>
       cards.map(card => card +' of '+ suit)
    )
)
```